# How to adjust spacing between images in a listview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, imagelist

I am using a image-list to show images in a list-view. So far I am able to display all the images in the image-list but spacing between each image is very big. So I used the [Send Message method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/a01d9fee-d2b6-4c03-982c-e55abccefb3d) which gave rise to another problem. Now when I click or move my mouse over(hot tracking enabled) any image the image becomes invisible. How can I solve this problem ?

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=False)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
    End Function

    Const LVM_FIRST As Integer = &H1000
    Const LVM_SETICONSPACING As Integer = LVM_FIRST + 53

    Public Sub SetSpacing(ByVal x As Int16, ByVal y As Int16)
        SendMessage(Me.ListView1.Handle, LVM_SETICONSPACING, 0, x * 65536 + y)
        Me.ListView1.Refresh()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Display()
        For i As Integer = 0 To ImageList1.Images.Count - 1
            Dim item As New ListViewItem()
            item.ImageIndex = i
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Display()
        SetSpacing(200, 16)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Before Mouse-Move:

[image]

After Mouse-Move:

[image]

<del>Also I have this big left margin although listview margin is set to All = 3</del>

The First column of Images is not being displayed !!!

[image]

Comment: `LVM_SETICONSPACING` applies only to ListViews with the "Icon" view style. Is that what you're using?

Comment: @CodyGray I am using Listview.View = LargeIcon

Answer (score 0):

In your x and y arguments, you have to include the width and the height of the icons.

MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761176(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

> Values for lParam are relative to the upper-left corner of an icon
>   bitmap. Therefore, to set spacing between icons that do not overlap,
>   the lParam values must include the size of the icon, plus the amount
>   of empty space desired between icons. Values that do not include the
>   width of the icon will result in overlaps.

And you need to invert:

```
x * 65536 + y -> x + y * 65536
```

y is in the HIWORD, x is in the LOWORD

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I used with LargeIcon and works, from here:
https://qdevblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/c-listview-item-spacing.html

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam); 

public int MakeLong(short lowPart, short highPart)
{
     return (int)(((ushort)lowPart) | (uint)(highPart << 16));
}
  
public void ListViewItem_SetSpacing(ListView listview, short leftPadding, short topPadding) 
{     
    const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;     
    const int LVM_SETICONSPACING = LVM_FIRST + 53;     
    SendMessage(listview.Handle, LVM_SETICONSPACING, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)MakeLong(leftPadding, topPadding));      
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
ListViewItem_SetSpacing(this.listView1, 96 + 16, 96 + 16); // width image + H spacing, height image + V spacing
```